# AS3: Resizing a sprite without resizing its BitmapFill (or its contents for that matter)?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, resize, bitmap, sprite

**Edit #2** I've found the solution, it was more simple than I could have hoped. Thanks for your time. =) (Answered my own question with full solution)

**Edit:** My apologies that my post was not transparent enough.. I will try to iterate for a little more clarity. I am not simply trying to contain things and have the container resize without the contents resizing. I would just use a simple MovieClip for that.. **My main focus is on the use of BitmapFill**. I'm trying to make a repeating background image for a container; thus far I'm able to draw my BitmapFill sprite to the size I want. (Which is the stage's height) but when the stage is resized, I want to re-size my container but have my containers BitmapFill crop or add more as the window is resized bigger or smaller. Allow me to illustrate what I mean:

[image]

I hope this clears up any confusion and helps with any straighter answers.

**------- Original post:**

I've got a simple rectangle sprite that fills with a bitmap from the library and a simple resize handler function that detects when the window has been resized.

What I would like to do is have my rectangle resize to the height of the stage.stageHeight maintaining its bitmap fill, but **not resizing** the bitmap fill or any children within the sprite.

From what I've read, this is a little tricky because the sprite resizes in relation to what it contains.. or.. something like that.. I really don't know any more.. I saw one example where a person extended the sprite class but I don't know why or how..

in my library there is an image called 'pattern' and my code looks like this:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler, false, 0, true);

var bgData:pattern = new pattern(0,0);
var bg:Sprite = new Sprite();

bg.graphics.beginBitmapFill(bgData, null, true, false);
bg.graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, 80, stage.stageHeight);
bg.graphics.endFill();
addChild(bg);

function resizeHandler(e:Event=null):void 
{
 trace("dimensions are: " + stage.stageWidth + " x " + stage.stageHeight);
 bg.height = stage.stageHeight;  //simply makes the fill resize also
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, well I'm dull. The answer was quite simple.

All I needed to do was clear the graphics then redraw them..

I wasn't aware of the clear(); function..

the full revised code is as follows:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler, false, 0, true);

var bgData:pattern = new pattern(0,0);
var bg:Sprite = new Sprite();

bg.graphics.beginBitmapFill(bgData, null, true, false);
bg.graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, 80, stage.stageHeight);
bg.graphics.endFill();
addChild(bg);

function resizeHandler(e:Event=null):void 
{
 trace("dimensions are: " + stage.stageWidth + " x " + stage.stageHeight);
 bg.graphics.clear();

 bg.graphics.beginBitmapFill(bgData, null, true, false);
 bg.graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, 80, stage.stageHeight);

 bg.graphics.endFill();
}
```

thanks all, sorry for this potential waste of space.

Answer (score 1):

Since a Sprite will resize to its content, you can use a Shape to resize your Sprite. Changing the Shape size will effectively resize the Sprite without resizing the Sprite's other children.

```
var bg:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild( bg );

var fill:Shape = new Shape();
//you can make the fill transparent
with( fill )
{
   graphics.beginFill( 0 , 0 );
   graphics.drawRect( 0 , 0 , anyWidth  , anhyHeight );
   graphics.endFill();
}
bg.addChild(fill);

//then add the fill that you want visible
var bgFill:Sprite = new Sprite();
//add the graphics here
bg.addChild(bgFill );


function resizeSprite(event:Event ):void
{
    // bgFill will not be resized
    fill.width = stage.stageWidth;
    fill.height = stage.stageHeight;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply, I appreciate the effort you have taken to write out this response, however after inspecting and playing with your code, it looks like you're merely using a sprite as a container for another sprite.. this is kind of defeating the purpose of my problem as i am perfectly aware of this method of containment.  I've updated my post to be as clear as i can, i hope you can help me with this revised question =) ~PtK

Comment: No problem , I did actually miss the BitmapFill bit :( I got a tendency to read too quickly! In any case, congrats for your answer, howewer much one can help, I think it's always more gratifying to find the answer yourself :)